# When i click a button, it displays many alerts, stacks and overlaps

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

i want to sync the task, which when i click sync on the side menu, it will call the function in data.service.ts and it will display alert.

private async presentAlert(message) {

```
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        message: message,
        buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

this is the code, where i want to sync the task on data.service.ts

```
sync_task()
    {

    let body = new FormData();

    body.append('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));

    this.apiService.syncDataFromForm('/tasks', body)
    .then((result: any) => {

    if(result.data)
    {
    let form_data = result.data;
    console.log("task synced");
    console.log(form_data);

    this.deleteTask();
    this.deleteTaskList();
    this.deleteBuildingDetails();

    console.log(form_data);

    for(let data of result.data) {

    var submission_id = data.submission_id;
    var project_name = data.project_name;
    var status = '0';
    var building_submission_id = data.building.submission_id;
    var building_data = JSON.stringify(data.building.data);

    console.log("building_data");
    console.log(building_data);

    this.insertTask(submission_id, project_name, status);

    for(let formData of data.data)
    {
    console.log("all form data");
    console.log(formData);

    var form_id = formData.form_id;
    var data_id = formData.id;
    var form_name = formData.form_name;
    var submission_group = formData.submission_group;

    console.log("form_id");
    console.log(formData.form_id);

    this.insertTaskList(submission_id, data_id, form_id, form_name,submission_group);
    }

    this.insertBuildingDetails(submission_id, building_submission_id, building_data);
    }

    this.authState.next(false);
    this.presentAlert('Successfully synced!');
    this.menuCtrl.close();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
    } else {
    this.presentAlert('Uh oh!, sync failed! ');
    }

    });
    }
```

this code in side menu

```
sync_task()
  {

    this.data.sync_task();
  }
```

i don't know why the alert display too many times. the alert stacking up until the background turns dark. and i need to click ok too many times to clear that.

Comment: It depends where do you call this chunk of code, maybe this is in an `ionViewWillEnter` method that will subscribe every time you visit the page (you can revisit it multiple times)... What you need to do is to put a counter inside the subscribe  method so that you can check how many subscriptions are there.

Comment: Please share the full block from where `this.presentAlert()` is being called. Are you sure that that method is not getting called multiple times?

Comment: i have edit my code. @arif08

Comment: Do you get repeated console.log as well?

Comment: yes. every data sync, the alert repeated as well, how to display one alert only@arif08